# how to group by multiple columns and do different agreggations on columns pandas

Tags: pandas

I have 631 columns, and i want to group by 2 of them and perform the aggregation doing a `sum()` with all the other columns except the last one, for which I want the `max()`.

This is with pandas, python, jupyter notebook:

```
merged_df.groupby(['USER_ID','month']).agg({merged_group.iloc[:,0:630]:'sum',
                                           'convierte':'max'})
```

This doesn't work beacuase it shows:

> 'TypeError: 'DataFrame' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed'

Answer (score 0):

When creating your aggregation dictionary, you are setting the DataFrame as a key. DataFrames are mutable, and so it's complaining about that. You need `{'col_name' : 'sum'}` for your dictionary:

```
d = {x: 'sum' for x in merged_group.columns[0:630]}
d['convierte'] = 'max'

merged_df.groupby(['USER_ID', 'month']).agg(d)
```